# Get all files from my C drive - Python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, python-3.x

Here is what I try to do: 
I would like to get a list of all files that are heavier than 35 MB in my C drive.

Here is my code:

```
def getAllFileFromDirectory(directory, temp):
    files = os.listdir(directory)
    for file in files:
        if (os.path.isdir(file)):
            getAllFileFromDirectory(file, temp)
        elif (os.path.isfile(file) and os.path.getsize(file) > 35000000):
            temp.write(os.path.abspath(file))

def getFilesOutOfTheLimit():
    basePath = "C:/"
    tempFile = open('temp.txt', 'w')
    getAllFileFromDirectory(basePath, tempFile)
    tempFile.close()
    print("Get all files ... Done !")
```

For some reason, the interpreter doesn't go in the if-block inside 'getAllFileFromDirectory'.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and why (learning is my aim). How to fix it ?

Thanks a lot for your comments.

Comment: I tried to run that code locally (on a UNIX system so with `/` instead of `C:/`) and it worked perfectly, it just so happened that none of the files are larger than 35 MB in that directory. Are you sure you have files over 35MB instide `C:/`? Your code will only analyse files directly inside the `C:/` folder, not recursively traverse it to see all files in your drive.

Comment: @DavidGomes: are you sure about that last statement? According to that function, it should call itself recursively for folders.

Comment: Yeah, I was wrong. You should do `os.path.isdir(directory + file)` then because `os.path.isdir` can only know if something is a directory if you give it its full path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your code. Your problem was that `os.path.isdir` can only know if something is a directory if it receives the full path of it. So, I changed the code to the following and it works. Same thing for `os.path.getsize` and `os.path.isfile`.

```
import os

def getAllFileFromDirectory(directory, temp):
    files = os.listdir(directory)

    for file in files:
        if (os.path.isdir(directory + file)):
            if file[0] == '.': continue  # i added this because i'm on a UNIX system

            print(directory + file)
            getAllFileFromDirectory(directory + file, temp)
        elif (os.path.isfile(directory + file) and os.path.getsize(directory + file) > 35000000):
            temp.write(os.path.abspath(file))

def getFilesOutOfTheLimit():
    basePath = "/"
    tempFile = open('temp.txt', 'w')

    getAllFileFromDirectory(basePath, tempFile)
    tempFile.close()
    print("Get all files ... Done !")

getFilesOutOfTheLimit()
```

Comment: You should use `os.path.join(directory, file)` for maximum reliability. Of course, the OP should also just be using `os.walk` in the first place.

Comment: This will perform considerably better in 3.5+ using `os.walk`, which switched to using `os.scandir` instead of `os.listdir`. For Windows, it also needs to use Unicode strings and the base path on drive C: should be `u"\\\\?\\C:\\"`. This allows path lengths up to about 32,760 characters as opposed to the default limit of 260 characters.

Comment: Is it possible to have a look at a sample of the os.walk manner ?